# MacOS App Runs in Debug and Release in Xcode, but not Standalone

Tags: xcode, macos

I've been working on my apps for months and never had problem get it to run in debug. When I went to create my first release, I get this error:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/MacOSGlues.framework/Versions/A/MacOSGlues
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JazzCat-ffbfdfrcekhzjacupibevqyrfyoh/Build/Products/Debug/jazzcat.app/Contents/MacOS/jazzcat
Reason: image not found
```

I'm doing the build in a workspace that also contains another module. The error references one of the files in that module.

To build the release version, I edited the scheme and changed "Build Configuration" to release. I located the app in Finder and ran it to get the error. If I press Cmd R in xcode, the release version runs fine. It's only when I try to run it directly (i.e., outside of Xcode).

Is there a parallel set up that I have to do for release that includes some or all that is set up for debug? I would have thought this would have been a common problem and there would already be an answer. I couldn't find one. This is a snap shot of the workspace in Xcode. I assuming the files are red because they aren't under version control whereas the bulk of the project is.

[image]

There are no entries in the "Target Dependencies" in the "Build Phases". When I attempt to add one, my only choices are the source code files in my own project.

The SwiftAE project is source code.

Under jazzcat/Build Settings/Search Paths/Framework Search Paths nothing is set for debug, which works, or release.

Comment: does JazzCat have MacOSGlues in Xcode-build-phase in target dependency?

Comment: and remove your framework from linked fromeworks and library. instead add them in your embedded binaries. it will appear then in both sections.

Comment: What are the values of Build settings > *`Framework Search Paths`* for Debug and for Release?

Comment: I can only find "Build Settings" "Search Paths". There are no debug and release option/views. I'm looking in the same path as shown above.

Comment: found Framework search paths, nothing is set.

Comment: @curt the error library not loaded means the binary for that framework doesn't exist in your app bundle. just add your libraries to the "embedded binaries" section and add them as dependency in order to be built.

Comment: @HashmatKhalil, that did it. Add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Library not loaded` mostly occurs when Library Dependency is not configured properly. First, the libraries should be built either by manual building or the better way by dependency configuration. That way the library will be built automatically.

[image: here a library has dependencies onther Libs]

Adding Frameworks should be configured in `Embedded Binaries` section

[image: Like this example by Curt]

@curt: I hope you don't mind that I relinked your screenshot.

Comment: Not at all, it should be in the answer.