# Onesignal Unity IOS Build Symbol not found error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, onesignal

I am developed a game with Unity3D and exported IOS build. Xcode build project succesfully but App crash on launch.

Firstly I got this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignalXC8.framework/OneSignalXC8   Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxx
>
> Reason: image not found

After this, I added OneSignalXC8 framework to embeded binaries and error changed.

> dyld: Symbol not found: __TMaCs29_NativeDictionaryStorageOwner
>     Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxx.app/Frameworks/OneSignalXC8.framework/OneSignalXC8
>     Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
>    in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxx.app/Frameworks/OneSignalXC8.framework/OneSignalXC8

After this error, I set "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to "Yes". Like saying here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43117611/793880

But still I got same last error. How can I solve this?

- I am using Xcode 8.3.3
- I am using Unity 5.6.1f1
- Unity exporting Xcode Project not workspace
- I am using Objective-C

Thanks

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996811/883954

Comment: library already imported embeded binaries and linked frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I deleted OneSignal folder from Unity project.
- Download last released plugin package from https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Unity-SDK
- Import Unity project and build.
- Runnning successfully